# ews-java-api: Error on item update: At least one recipient isn't valid

Tags: java, exchangewebservices

I am working on a tool which uses ews-java-api to create, update and delete calendar items in Outlook agenda. It has been working fine, but now sometimes when it tries to update some calendar item, I get following error:

```
microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.exception.service.remote.ServiceResponseException: At least one recipient isn't valid., A message can't be sent because it contains no recipients.
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.response.ServiceResponse.internalThrowIfNecessary(ServiceResponse.java:278)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.response.ServiceResponse.throwIfNecessary(ServiceResponse.java:267)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.MultiResponseServiceRequest.execute(MultiResponseServiceRequest.java:165)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeService.internalUpdateItems(ExchangeService.java:691)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeService.updateItem(ExchangeService.java:762)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.service.item.Item.internalUpdate(Item.java:279)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.service.item.Item.update(Item.java:400)
at be.vrt.quintiqexchange.main.QuintiqAdapter.insertUpdateCalendarItems(QuintiqAdapter.java:879)
at be.vrt.quintiqexchange.main.QuintiqAdapter.updateCalendarItems(QuintiqAdapter.java:796)
at be.vrt.quintiqexchange.main.QuintiqAdapter.run(QuintiqAdapter.java:286)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Recently all the exchange accounts have been migrated from local Outlook servers to Office365 cloud servers. Maybe this has something to do with it? Or anybody have any idea on what is going wrong?

Following code is to perform the update for an item:

```
Item it = alitems.get(i);
...
it.update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite);
```

Following is the url being used to access office365 ews:

```
exchangewebservice = https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx
```

Thanks in advance

Edit: I use ews-java-api version 2.0

Edit: Here you can see that the error occurs on one line and than the next line, with the same recipient it doesn't occur...

```
microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.exception.service.remote.ServiceResponseException: At least one recipient isn't valid., A message can't be sent because it contains no recipients.
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.response.ServiceResponse.internalThrowIfNecessary(ServiceResponse.java:278)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.response.ServiceResponse.throwIfNecessary(ServiceResponse.java:267)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.MultiResponseServiceRequest.execute(MultiResponseServiceRequest.java:165)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeService.internalUpdateItems(ExchangeService.java:691)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeService.updateItem(ExchangeService.java:762)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.service.item.Item.internalUpdate(Item.java:279)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.service.item.Item.update(Item.java:400)
    at be.vrt.quintiqexchange.main.QuintiqAdapter.insertUpdateCalendarItems(QuintiqAdapter.java:880)
    at be.vrt.quintiqexchange.main.QuintiqAdapter.updateCalendarItems(QuintiqAdapter.java:703)
    at be.vrt.quintiqexchange.main.QuintiqAdapter.run(QuintiqAdapter.java:283)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
WARN  be.vrt.quintiqexchange.main.QuintiqAdapter - At least one recipient isn't valid., A message can't be sent because it contains no recipients.by UPDATE for subject:  on Thu Jun 23 14:00:00 CEST 2016 Thu Jun 23 19:00:00 CEST 2016 of user name.lastname@domain.com
INFO  be.vrt.quintiqexchange.main.QuintiqAdapter - Appointment updated for subject: NIET DAG on Fri Aug 05 10:00:00 CEST 2016 Fri Aug 05 18:00:00 CEST 2016 of user name.lastname@domain.com
INFO  be.vrt.quintiqexchange.main.QuintiqAdapter - Appointment updated for subject: PROEF st5 on Mon Aug 22 10:00:00 CEST 2016 Mon Aug 22 20:30:00 CEST 2016 of user name.lastname@domain.com
```

This means that the recipient isn't really the issue, I guess...

p.s. I replaced the original mailaddress but believe me, it's a correct mailadres :)

Comment: I know nothing about Java and EWS, but if you look at the [UpdateItem documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa581084(v=exchg.150).aspx) you'll see that there's also a MessageDisposition. You are not specifying any. Maybe this is trying to send notifications to a user that does not exist...

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. Well, the update method in the ews-java-api sets the MessageDisposition to SaveOnly. Also it sets the SendInvitationsOrCancellationsMode to null. In c# there's an overload method where you can set the SendInvitationsOrCancellationsMode but not in Java...

Comment: I think you need to set valid recipient @MaartenMeeusen

Comment: Yes, that's what the says and that's just the thing. It has been working for a long time and suddenly it randomly starts giving me these errors. But the recipients addresses did not change.. Also it can work with one recipient and then 1 min after it doesn't work anymore for the same recipient.. That's why it's so strange...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, if the address is not properly trimmed and has any whitespace characters at all, EWS vomits this exception up.